# Keras: Spatial pyramid pooling not working, problem in training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

We're working on Spatial Pyramid Pooling starting from this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729v4.pdf. We implemented this code, but it's not working correctly (the loss doesn't decrease), probably we're missing something about the training, may you help us?

This is the SPP layer

```
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np    from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, Activation, MaxPooling2D, Dense


class SpatialPyramidPooling(Layer):
"""Spatial pyramid pooling layer for 2D inputs.
See Spatial Pyramid Pooling in Deep Convolutional Networks for Visual Recognition,
K. He, X. Zhang, S. Ren, J. Sun
# Arguments
    pool_list: list of int
        List of pooling regions to use. The length of the list is the number of pooling regions,
        each int in the list is the number of regions in that pool. For example [1,2,4] would be 3
        regions with 1, 2x2 and 4x4 max pools, so 21 outputs per feature map
# Input shape
    4D tensor with shape:
    `(samples, channels, rows, cols)` if dim_ordering='th'
    or 4D tensor with shape:
    `(samples, rows, cols, channels)` if dim_ordering='tf'.
# Output shape
    2D tensor with shape:
    `(samples, channels * sum([i * i for i in pool_list])`

def __init__(self, pool_list, **kwargs):

    self.dim_ordering = K.image_data_format()
    assert self.dim_ordering in {'channels_last', 'channels_first'}, 'dim_ordering must be in {channels_last, channels_first}'

    self.pool_list = pool_list

    self.num_outputs_per_channel = sum([i * i for i in pool_list])

    super(SpatialPyramidPooling, self).__init__(**kwargs)

def build(self, input_shape):
    if self.dim_ordering == 'channels_first':
        self.nb_channels = input_shape[1]
    elif self.dim_ordering == 'channels_last':
        self.nb_channels = input_shape[3]

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], self.nb_channels * self.num_outputs_per_channel)

def get_config(self):
    config = {'pool_list': self.pool_list}
    base_config = super(SpatialPyramidPooling, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))

def call(self, x, mask=None):

    input_shape = K.shape(x)

    if self.dim_ordering == 'channels_first':
        num_rows = input_shape[2]
        num_cols = input_shape[3]
    elif self.dim_ordering == 'channels_last':
        num_rows = input_shape[1]
        num_cols = input_shape[2]

    row_length = [K.cast(num_rows, 'float32') / i for i in self.pool_list]
    col_length = [K.cast(num_cols, 'float32') / i for i in self.pool_list]

    outputs = []

    if self.dim_ordering == 'channels_first':
        for pool_num, num_pool_regions in enumerate(self.pool_list):
            for jy in range(num_pool_regions):
                for ix in range(num_pool_regions):
                    x1 = ix * col_length[pool_num]
                    x2 = ix * col_length[pool_num] + col_length[pool_num]
                    y1 = jy * row_length[pool_num]
                    y2 = jy * row_length[pool_num] + row_length[pool_num]

                    x1 = K.cast(K.round(x1), 'int32')
                    x2 = K.cast(K.round(x2), 'int32')
                    y1 = K.cast(K.round(y1), 'int32')
                    y2 = K.cast(K.round(y2), 'int32')
                    new_shape = [input_shape[0], input_shape[1],
                                 y2 - y1, x2 - x1]
                    x_crop = x[:, :, y1:y2, x1:x2]
                    xm = K.reshape(x_crop, new_shape)
                    pooled_val = K.max(xm, axis=(2, 3))
                    outputs.append(pooled_val)

    elif self.dim_ordering == 'channels_last':
        for pool_num, num_pool_regions in enumerate(self.pool_list):
            for jy in range(num_pool_regions):
                for ix in range(num_pool_regions):
                    x1 = ix * col_length[pool_num]
                    x2 = ix * col_length[pool_num] + col_length[pool_num]
                    y1 = jy * row_length[pool_num]
                    y2 = jy * row_length[pool_num] + row_length[pool_num]

                    x1 = K.cast(K.round(x1), 'int32')
                    x2 = K.cast(K.round(x2), 'int32')
                    y1 = K.cast(K.round(y1), 'int32')
                    y2 = K.cast(K.round(y2), 'int32')

                    new_shape = [input_shape[0], y2 - y1,
                                 x2 - x1, input_shape[3]]

                    x_crop = x[:, y1:y2, x1:x2, :]
                    xm = K.reshape(x_crop, new_shape)
                    pooled_val = K.max(xm, axis=(1, 2))
                    outputs.append(pooled_val)

    if self.dim_ordering == 'channels_first':
        outputs = K.concatenate(outputs)
    elif self.dim_ordering == 'channels_last':
        #outputs = K.concatenate(outputs,axis = 1)
        #outputs = K.concatenate(outputs)
        #outputs = K.reshape(outputs,(len(self.pool_list),self.num_outputs_per_channel,input_shape[0],input_shape[1]))
        #outputs = K.permute_dimensions(outputs,(3,1,0,2))
        outputs = K.reshape(outputs,(input_shape[0], self.num_outputs_per_channel * self.nb_channels))

    return outputs
```

This is the model

```
batch_size = 32
num_channels = 3
num_classes = 5

model = Sequential()
# uses theano ordering. Note that we leave the image size as None to allow multiple image sizes
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same', input_shape=(None, None,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(SpatialPyramidPooling([1, 2, 4]))
print(model.output_shape)
print(model.summary())
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
print(model.output_shape)
print(model.summary())

#model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
  metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This is the data upload and fitting of the model

```
batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file(origin=dataset_url, 
                                   fname='flower_photos', 
                                   untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
    train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=123,
    image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)



val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

from tensorflow.keras import layers

normalization_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1./255)

normalized_ds = train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (normalization_layer(x), y))
image_batch, labels_batch = next(iter(normalized_ds))
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
print(train_ds)

#MODEL FIT
model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=10
)
```